# ModalBottomSheet progress for manage animation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

I want to manage the shape of the ModalBottomSheet depending on their position on the screen.

The idea is that, when it is appearing from bottom, the corners have 2.dp for example, and while the sheet is going up until the top of the screen, the corners will be reduced to 0.dp.

I've checked the SheetState but it doesn't have any information about the progress:

```
@Stable
@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
class SheetState(
    internal val skipPartiallyExpanded: Boolean,
    initialValue: SheetValue = Hidden,
    confirmValueChange: (SheetValue) -> Boolean = { true },
    internal val skipHiddenState: Boolean = false,
)
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/SheetState

We can slide this component with the finger (if it's not bocked), so my approach to get the goal, was to get some value that will be updated with the position of the sheet to get the relative position regarding to the top of the screen, so we can calculate the percent of the radius to be applied, from 2.dp in the bottom, to 0.dp in the top, but seems that doesn't exists a value for this in the ModalBottomSheet state.

Any idea to achieve this?

Comment: Created an issue in the issue tracker.  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/287390076

Comment: I had an issue opened too -> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/287110112. Thanks!